# Starting new 8.5 site is it safe to delete and reuse field_image field

Tags: 8, media

I am starting a new 8.5 website and using the core media module. I want to know if it is safe to delete the field_image field from the Article content type and replace it with a field with the same name but instead make it a media reference field. I have searched high and low and it is not clear as to if this will cause me issues with future versions of Drupal.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Hi Chris, it would be both polite and correct to give some kind of feedback. Don't keep just throwing questions without accepting any answers as otherwise you discourage others to keep helping you.

Comment: I decided to leave well enough alone because I cannot get a reliable answer as to what the media devs are thinking in regards to upgrading the straight file image field. So for the time being I will continue with the wait and see game.

Comment: Good to know about your choices for posterity cases.

Answer (score 2):

Any field could be deleted and re-created per your preferences and it won't cause any problems in the future as Drupal 8 does not require fields of certain machine names to be of certain types only.

Comment: In general, I'd agree. However, I'd probably add the info, that some contributed modules/themes might sometimes rely on certain field types when providing preprocessing/templates for the default fields/content types added by a plain Drupal installation.